# Java 8 Convert given time and time zone to UTC time

Tags: java, java-8, utc, java-time

I have a time with string type like: `"2015-01-05 17:00"` and `ZoneId` is `"Australia/Sydney"`.

How can I convert this time information to the corresponding to UTC time (accounting for DST) using Java 8?

Comment: What do you mean by "UTC Time"? Do you want an Instant? or a java.sql.Date? Or a number of millis since the epoch?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You are looking for `ZonedDateTime` class in Java8 - a complete date-time with time-zone and resolved offset from UTC/Greenwich. In terms of design, this class should be viewed primarily as the combination of a `LocalDateTime` and a `ZoneId`. The `ZoneOffset` is a vital, but secondary, piece of information, used to ensure that the class represents an instant, especially during a daylight savings overlap.

For example:

```
ZoneId australia = ZoneId.of("Australia/Sydney");
String str = "2015-01-05 17:00";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
LocalDateTime localtDateAndTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
ZonedDateTime dateAndTimeInSydney = ZonedDateTime.of(localtDateAndTime, australia );

System.out.println("Current date and time in a particular timezone : " + dateAndTimeInSydney);

ZonedDateTime utcDate = dateAndTimeInSydney.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);

System.out.println("Current date and time in UTC : " + utcDate);
```

Comment: It seems this result is not what I want. I want to convert to the UTC time and store UTC time in my database. The ZonedDateTime is not what I want and can't map to DB column type.

Comment: Sorry I've added conversion to UTC in example.

Comment: Cool, it seems we must convert LocalDateTime to the ZonedDateTime and then we can convert between different timezone. Thanks.

Comment: @MateuszSroka - My time stamp has zero millis '2021-04-11 10:25:33.000'. This code truncates the zeros. How to show the zeros also? I posted a related question over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67102239/how-to-convert-a-datetime-string-into-utc-in-java

Answer (score 25):

An alternative to the existing answer is to setup the formatter with the appropriate time zone:

```
String input = "2015-01-05 17:00";
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Australia/Sydney");

DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").withZone(zone);
ZonedDateTime utc = ZonedDateTime.parse(input, fmt).withZoneSameInstant(UTC);
```

Since you want to interact with a database, you may need a `java.sql.Timestamp`, in which case you don't need to explicitly convert to a UTC time but can use an Instant instead:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(input, fmt);
Timestamp sqlTs = Timestamp.from(zdt.toInstant());
```

Comment: What is UTC variable on this context?

Comment: It's a date/time, in UTC time zone, which corresponds to the same instant as "input" in Sydney. So in this case, it's going to be the same date but at 6am.

Answer (score 1):

```
   **// Refactored Logic**     

        ZoneId australia = ZoneId.of("Australia/Sydney");
        ZoneId utcZoneID= ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC");
        String ausTime = "2015-01-05 17:00";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

        //converting in datetime of java8
        LocalDateTime ausDateAndTime = LocalDateTime.parse(ausTime, formatter);

        // DateTime With Zone
        ZonedDateTime utcDateAndTime = ausDateAndTime.atZone(utcZoneID);
        // output - 2015-01-05T17:00Z[Etc/UTC]

        // With Formating DateTime
        String utcDateTime = utcDateAndTime.format(formatter);
        // output - 2015-01-05 17:00
```