# Change timezone of Date object without changing date

Tags: java-8, jodatime

Can I change the timezone of Date object in my java code without changing the date? 
When I write
`Date date = new Date(longValue);`
I get this date in my local timezone. I want to get this date but my timezone should be one present in DB (not local) for my userID (for eg "America/Chicago").

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Always save date in DB using UTC time, and you can get any time zone date when needed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime zdtMontreal = 
    ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) );

ZonedDateTime zdtAuckland = 
    zdtMontreal.withZoneSameLocal( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) );
```

***Not* the same moment.** The `zdtAuckland` moment occurred *several hours earlier*.

Be certain that is truly your intention. I have a sinking feeling you are doing the wrong thing, confused about how date-time handling works. Date-time work *is* confusing. Be sure to search and study Stack Overflow.

## java.time

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

The `Local…` classes purposely have no time zone or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) information.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2016 , Month.January , 23 ); // 2016-01-23
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 12 , 34 , 56 );  // 12:34:56
```

These values do *not* yet represent a point on the timeline. Would that be the noon hour of Auckland NZ, Paris FR, or Montréal CA? We must apply a time zone to determine an actual moment. We apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` or `CST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId zMontreal = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdtMontreal = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , zMontreal );
```

To see a string representing this value in the standard ISO 8601 format, call `toString`. Actually, the `ZonedDateTime` class extends the standard format by wisely appending the name of the time zone in square brackets.

```
String outputMontreal = zdtMontreal.toString();
```

> 2016-01-23T12:34:56-05:00[America/Montreal]

To get the same date and same time-of-day in another time zone, repeat the process.

```
ZoneId zParis = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" );
ZonedDateTime zdtParis = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , zParis );

ZoneId zAuckland = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" );
ZonedDateTime zdtAuckland = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , zAuckland );
```

But know that you are getting a *different* moment in time. Noon in Auckland happens several hours before noon in Paris, and noon in Montréal is even later, for three **different points in time** that happen to share coincidentally the same [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time).

> 2016-01-23T12:34:56-05:00[America/Montreal]
>
> 2016-01-23T12:34:56+01:00[Europe/Paris]
>
> 2016-01-23T12:34:56+13:00[Pacific/Auckland]

[image]

## Current moment

To get the current moment, call `Instant.now`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instance = Instance.now();
```

Apply a `ZoneId` to adjust into a time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instance.atZone( z );
```

Repeat the process for other desired time zones, similar to what we did further above.

As a shortcut, you can get a `ZonedDateTime` directly.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtMontreal = ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) );
```

And as another shortcut, you can apply a different time zone while retaining the same date and same time-of-day (the same wall-clock time). Call [`ZonedDateTime::withZoneSameLocal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameLocal-java.time.ZoneId-).

```
ZonedDateTime zdtAuckland = zdtMontreal.withZoneSameLocal( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) );
```

I repeat: This results is *different* points on the time line. The `zdtAuckland` is happening several hours before `zdtMontreal` occurs.

To keep the same moment, instead call [`ZonedDateTime::withZoneSameInstant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant-java.time.ZoneId-).

## Database

Usually best to store your date-time values in a database in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Already discussed extensively on Stack Overflow. Search for more info.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You may find `ZonedDateTime` quite helpful:

[Java 8 Convert given time and time zone to UTC time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34605691/java-8-convert-given-time-and-time-zone-to-utc-time)

Alternatively you can create another `Date` object and apply some offset to it manually.

Comment: i have already tried it but it did not solve my problem. I only want to change my timezone and not date. For eg i want this date 11/23/2016, 4:16 PM EST to be changed to 11/23/2016, 4:16 PM CST. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

An example of how to do it using Java8 `ZonedDateTime` class:

```
Date date = new Date(longValue);
ZoneId = ZoneId.of("America/Chicago");
ZonedDateTime dt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), zoneId);
```

You've tagged the question with Joda, but really with Java8 you don't need it anymore.

Comment: i have already tried it but it did not solve my problem. I only want to change my timezone and not date. For eg i want this date 11/23/2016, 4:16 PM EST to be changed to 11/23/2016, 4:16 PM CST. Your example changes the date also.