# How to change timezone in ZonedDateTime for Java

Tags: java, timezone, zoneddatetime, date

What I mean is this. Suppose I have a date object that is May 1, 2018, 12:00AM.  I would like to create a `ZonedDateTime` object that is May 1, 2018, 12:00AM but of ANOTHER time zone (say EST). Because if I pass in that date object into `ZonedDateTime`, it treats that date object as UTC (so it treats it as May 1 2018, 12:00AM GMT), and I want it to preserve that date field values but change the timzeone to EST (May 1st 2018, 12:00AM EST). Is there a way to do this in Java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change timezone of Date object without changing date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41004755/change-timezone-of-date-object-without-changing-date)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you need is a `LocalDate`:

```
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2018, Month.MAY, 1);
```

This will be understood in all time zones and will never be anything else than May 1. The “Local” in this and other class names in `java.time` means “without timezone”.

If you do insist on a `ZonedDateTime`, the answer is `withZoneSameLocal`:

```
    ZonedDateTime zdt = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    ZonedDateTime inEst = zdt.withZoneSameLocal(ZoneId.of("Australia/Brisbane"));
    System.out.println(inEst);
```

Output:

> 2018-05-01T00:00+10:00[Australia/Brisbane]

Don’t rely on EST or other three and four letter time zone abbreviations. EST, for example, is ambiguous (used both in North America and Australia) and is not a time zone (used less than half of the year). Instead give region/city, for example America/Atikokan.

If by “a date object” you meant an object of the outdated `java.util.Date` class (avoid them if you can, prefer the modern classes in `java.time`):

```
    Date oldfashionedDate = // …;

    OffsetDateTime dateTime = oldfashionedDate.toInstant().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    if (! dateTime.toLocalTime().equals(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("java.util.Date was supposed to be at midnight in UTC but was " + dateTime);
    }
    LocalDate date = dateTime.toLocalDate();
    System.out.println(date);
```

Output:

> 2018-05-01