# Convert string local date with zoneId to UTC Offsetdate JAVA

Tags: java, date, java-8, utc, java-time

I'm trying to convert a Brazil local date to UTC format. I have developed my solution but I'm sure that it can be improved. I have been searching for others questions but without success.

My problem is that when I process the `Date` object with:

```
Instant endDateTime = questionDate.toInstant();
```

I receive a UTC date as `"2017-11-16T00:00:00Z"` but this should be Brazil local date (not correct because it has a trailing `"Z"`) and when I try to convert to UTC, I receive the same output.

In another hand, if I use `ZoneDateTime` class and build the date with `LocalDateTime` object I lose the seconds in the output: `"2017-11-16T02:00Z"`. This happens when I use:

```
LocalTime.of(hour, minutes, seconds);
```

I search into `LocalTime` class and I think this is because minutes or seconds are `0` but I'm not sure of it.

### Problems of the solution:

1. The response hasn't seconds
2. I hope Java 8 has a set of functions to make this more simple and clear

### Precondition:

- I can't use Joda library
- Result has to be `OffsetDateTime` class
- Input: Date `"2017-11-16"`
- Output: `"2017-11-16T02:00:00Z"`

### This is my solution:

```
private static OffsetDateTime processDate(Date questionDate) {
  Instant endDateTime = questionDate.toInstant();
  ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of(ZONEID);
  String [] date = endDateTime.toString().split("T");
  LocalDateTime localDateTime = convertLocalTimeToUtc(date);
  ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, zoneId);
  ZonedDateTime utcDate = zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
  return utcDate.toOffsetDateTime();
}

private static LocalDateTime convertLocalTimeToUtc(String[] dateFromCountry) {
  LocalDate date = processDate(dateFromCountry[0]);
  LocalTime time = processTime(dateFromCountry[1]);
  return  LocalDateTime.of(date, time);
}

private static LocalDate processDate(String dateFromCountry) {
  String [] partsOfDate = dateFromCountry.split("-");
  int year = Integer.parseInt(partsOfDate[0]);
  int month = Integer.parseInt(partsOfDate[1]);
  int day = Integer.parseInt(partsOfDate[2]);
  return LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
}

private static LocalTime processTime(String dateFromCountry) {
  String [] partsOfTime = dateFromCountry.split(":");
  int hour = Integer.parseInt(partsOfTime[0]);
  int minutes = Integer.parseInt(partsOfTime[1]);
  int seconds = Integer.parseInt(partsOfTime[2].substring(0,1));
  return LocalTime.of(hour,minutes,seconds);
}
```

Comment: Try the static method of OffsetDateTime class - ofInstant(Instant instant, ZoneId zone) returns the OffsetDateTime...

Comment: @Grasshopper I tried but It returns `"2017-11-16T22:00-02:00"` . It's like it was taking the original date as UTC date. I'm looking for the opposite behavior

Comment: What is your input? A java.util.Date or a java.sql.Date? Can you show the exact input (something like: `long millis = xxx; Date d = new Date(millis)`)?

Comment: And where do you get the date from? If from a database the problem could be solved by using a different column type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 Convert given time and time zone to UTC time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34605691/java-8-convert-given-time-and-time-zone-to-utc-time)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your input is a `java.util.Date`, you can get rid of all the string manipulation:

```
//simulate your input
Instant input = Instant.parse("2017-11-16T00:00:00Z");
Date d = Date.from(input);    

//transformation code starts here
Instant instant = d.toInstant();

ZonedDateTime localInstant = instant.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
ZonedDateTime sameLocalInBrazil = utcInstant.withZoneSameLocal(ZoneId.of("Brazil/East"));
OffsetDateTime sameInstantUtc = sameLocalInBrazil.toOffsetDateTime()
                                      .withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

This return an OffsetDateTime with value `2017-11-16T02:00Z` as you expect.

Note that an OffsetDateTime has no formatting - so the object does know that its seconds are set to 0 but the default `toString` method doesn't print them. If you want to print it with seconds, you can use a formatter:

```
//Formatting
System.out.println(sameInstantUtc.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT));
```

which prints `2017-11-16T02:00:00Z`

---

If your input is a `java.sql.Date`, you can use a slightly different strategy:

```
LocalDate d = sqlDate.toLocalDate();
ZonedDateTime localInstant = d.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

The rest of the code would be the same.